# Loading multiple dependent libraries via JNI and DllMain

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-native-interface

I have a JNI library that depends on a third party library.

I can load and use the library by first doing a `System.Load` on the third party library then doing `System.Load` on my library. This works.

I recently introduced a DllMain (does not do anything) in my library and now when the library is loaded I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: fullpath\name.dll: Can't find dependent libraries`

If I attach a native debugger to the process and set a breakpoint in the DllMain function the breakpoint is entered and the Library is loaded correctly (no UnsatisfiedLinkError )

Does anyone have any idea or pointers as to what might be going on?

Comment: The most common reason for this working when running under a debugger and not in production code is because the debugger is using a different PATH than the production code when loading the library

Comment: i'm using System.Load and specifying the full path. In any case, the debugger (MSVC) is attached to the process manually at some point between the process being loaded and the calls to System.Load so it should not be effecting the PATH (?). Running the java application with a debugger (eclipse debug mode) or without (eclipse run mode) does not make any difference to this behaviour.

Comment: DllMain does return True? What does the dependency walker show you in relation to the third party library?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in you didn't link dlls that your dll are using to you java runtime. It must be in your working directory or use -Djava.library.path=fullpath.